# passing form input name through hyperlink

Tags: php, html, pdo

I am trying to pass input tag value to the another page to  simply multiply the value of qty with price and return the updated price.The problem is when i pass the value of qty with get method it passes the value of qty only but does not pass another values.

**cart.php**

```
echo" <form method='get' name='form1' action='update_cart.php?id={$id}&name={$name}&price={$price}&qty=$_GET['qty']'>";//the problem comes here.

echo"<input type='number' name='qty' max='10'>
    <input type='submit' value='update'></form>";
```

**update_cart.php**

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : "";
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : "";
$qty=isset($_GET['qty'])? $_GET['qty']: "";
$price=isset($_GET['price'])? $_GET['price']: "";

$price=$price*$qty;
header('Location: cart.php?action=quantity_updated&id=' . $id . '&name=' . $name . '&price='.$price . '&qty='.$qty);
```

when i click on update button after giving qty a value it shows something like this.

```
http://localhost/abc/cart.php?action=quantity_updated&id=&name=&price=0&qty=2
```

Comment: your form send to update_cart.php, but you have Cart_Update.php shown, and your url is cart.php ...??

Comment: @Andrew i have edited my question. The thing is when i update the value at cart.php it passes the values to update_cart.php and then after calculating price it returns back to cart.php with updated price.

Answer (score 0):

`form method="get"` passes variables automatically.

You do (and can) not need to append query string to the `action` attribute.

You do however need to represent those data in your form, if with `<input type="hidden" name="qty" value="<?=$qty?>" />` style.

Answer (score 0):

if you want pass some values , you can choose 2 way for it :

you can use the input with hidden type in you form.
if you use hidden type input you can use data just on one page.

```
<form method='get' action='?????'>
<input type='hidden' name='?????' value='?????'>
<input type='hidden' name='?????' value='?????'>
....
...
..
<input type='number' name='qty' max='10'/>
<input type='submit' value='submit'/>
</form>
```

you can use session for save data and use it in another page.
if you use session, you can use data in all php pages.
on page 1:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['name']='value';
?>
```

on page 2:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['name']; // value
?>
```

Comment: can i use this session variable to be passed through link? as say.. ` action='update_cart.php?id={$id}&name={$name}&price={$price}&qty=$_SESSION['qty']'>`

Comment: @tabia session is a good approche for saving data that you need it in all part of your application (for example login information , cart  ,etc ... )
for your program is good to use hidden input for transfer data...

Comment: Alright! i tried sessions. But when i pass a number as session value it prints it on another page perfectly!! but when i tried `$_Session['qty']=$_Post['qty']` it isn't working!!

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for this line contains errors.

```
echo" <form method='get' name='form1' action='update_cart.php?id={$id}&name={$name}&price={$price}&qty=$_GET['qty']'>";
```

Change it to...

```
echo" <form method='get' name='form1' action='update_cart.php?id=".$id."&name=".$name."&price=".$price."&qty=".$_GET['qty']."'>";
```